# web3.py ContractEvents.myEvent.process_receipt decoding

Tags: web3.py, decoding

Here's a link to the docs for reference:

I have the following code:

```
txhash = "{hash}"
tx_receipt = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(txhash)
processed_logs = w3.eth.contract(address="{address}", abi=contract_abi).events[event_name]().process_receipt(tx_receipt)
```

If I just look at the log, the encoded data looks like:

```
AttributeDict({'address': '0x6f5dfB0eaF832fF0D4204EC85184b634C7946457', 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x2657856d1ce53ab9ff04e08d13029082b3e8f403e1076222cefee8ed5287593d'), 'blockNumber': 4133628, 'data': HexBytes('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'), 'logIndex': 36, 'removed': False, 'topics': [HexBytes('0xd85d4fdd7876f7e7ce4ebfe722811abb3513522a11add221d40de3baba0f3e2d'), HexBytes('0x000000000000000000000000f2c61e275d48efa8a6556529f60ce1e376510e0f')], 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x25a57f565a2a8bb999d3344d9dc5ad305cc38263d253ae2a530d49542f5edb0b'), 'transactionIndex': 2})
```

Where `data` is HexBytes and it looks to be encoded, however, when I run `process_receipt`, it is doing some decoding and I end up with the following log:

```
(AttributeDict({'args': AttributeDict({'policyMetadataLogic': '0xf2C61E275d48efA8a6556529F60cE1E376510e0F', 'policyMetadata': '0x471BB2d2f650F84E138852De8D9DD9dbC69bF0F3', 'initializationData': b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07#6A45EC\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\xb5<g><path fill='#fff' d='M94.528 446.858h-6.905v2.912h2.658v15.141h-3.424v2.911h10.199v-2.911h-2.528v-18.053ZM107.476 446.858h-6.904v2.912h2.657v15.141h-3.423v2.911h10.199v-2.911h-2.529v-18.053ZM117.016 457.442c.144-1.5 1.17-2.3 3.019-2.3 1.849 0 2.774.8 2.774 2.533v.422l-5.085.626c-3.019.379-5.388 1.703-5.388 4.688 0 2.97 2.239 4.673 5.633 4.673 2.846 0 4.103-1.092 4.695-2.024h.289v1.762h3.958v-9.55c0-4.164-2.658-6.042-6.789-6.042-4.161 0-6.703 1.878-7.006 4.775v.437h3.9Zm-.506 5.78c0-1.151.867-1.704 2.124-1.879l4.175-.553v.656c0 2.46-1.618 3.697-3.843 3.697-1.56 0-2.456-.757-2.456-1.921ZM130.126 467.822h3.9v-9.812c0-1.878.982-2.694 2.355-2.694 1.228 0 1.834.714 1.834 1.922v10.584h3.901v-9.812c0-1.878.982-2.694 2.34-2.694 1.242 0 1.835.714 1.835 1.922v10.584h3.914v-11.123c0-2.766-1.733-4.411-4.377-4.411-2.369 0-3.467 1.034-4.102 2.169h-.289c-.434-.99-1.503-2.169-3.698-2.169-2.153 0-3.091.903-3.612 1.82h-.289v-1.529h-3.712v15.243ZM157.105 457.442c.145-1.5 1.17-2.3 3.019-2.3 1.849 0 2.774.8 2.774 2.533v.422l-5.085.626c-3.02.379-5.388 1.703-5.388 4.688 0 2.97 2.239 4.673 5.633 4.673 2.846 0 4.103-1.092 4.695-2.024h.289v1.762H167v-9.55c0-4.164-2.658-6.042-6.789-6.042-4.161 0-6.703 1.878-7.006 4.775v.437h3.9Zm-.506 5.78c0-1.151.867-1.704 2.124-1.879l4.175-.553v.656c0 2.46-1.618 3.697-3.843 3.697-1.56 0-2.456-.757-2.456-1.921Z'/><g fill='#6A45EC'><path d='M36.956 458.249a1.37 1.37 0 0 1 .39-.942c.245-.251.577-.397.927-.406H55.8a6.262 6.262 0 0 0 4.458-1.855 6.352 6.352 0 0 0 1.369-2.06 6.406 6.406 0 0 0 .482-2.433V428h-4.96v22.553a1.371 1.371 0 0 1-.389.942 1.351 1.351 0 0 1-.927.407H38.29a6.263 6.263 0 0 0-4.445 1.861A6.383 6.383 0 0 0 32 458.249v15.568h4.956v-15.568ZM64.304 432.298h-.22l.21.213v4.65h4.561l2.14 2.179a6.286 6.286 0 0 0-3.617 2.205 6.394 6.394 0 0 0-1.422 4.016v28.262h4.936v-28.269c.005-.356.148-.696.397-.948.25-.252.587-.395.94-.4h.76c2.912 0 3.9-1.638 4.192-2.325.293-.688.744-2.565-1.316-4.651l-4.831-4.915H69.53M51.193 471.362c1.083 0 2.154.216 3.153.638a8.153 8.153 0 0 1 2.665 1.817h6a13.224 13.224 0 0 0-4.85-5.438 13.059 13.059 0 0 0-6.968-2.017c-2.464 0-4.879.699-6.968 2.017a13.225 13.225 0 0 0-4.85 5.438h6A8.154 8.154 0 0 1 48.038 472a8.101 8.101 0 0 1 3.154-.638Z'/></g></g>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"}), 'event': 'PolicyMetadataSet', 'logIndex': 36, 'transactionIndex': 2, 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x25a57f565a2a8bb999d3344d9dc5ad305cc38263d253ae2a530d49542f5edb0b'), 'address': '0x6f5dfB0eaF832fF0D4204EC85184b634C7946457', 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x2657856d1ce53ab9ff04e08d13029082b3e8f403e1076222cefee8ed5287593d'), 'blockNumber': 4133628}),)
```

Here, `initializationData` seems to have been decoded rather than just giving me the full bytecode like I would expect.

For example: I see

```
x00\x00\x00\x00\x07#6A45EC\x00\x00\x00\x00...
```

With the "color" property decoded. I think that's how it's supposed to work but it gives me the wrong number of bytes.

This works for other events in my code so I am not sure what's happening with this one, could it be a bug with web3.py or something I'm missing?

Here's the event for reference:

https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x6f5dfB0eaF832fF0D4204EC85184b634C7946457#events

Thank you

EDIT:

Adding more context on what I'm trying to accomplish:

This is troublesome because I am using `web3.eth_abi` and later in my code I am trying to decode:

`decode('(string,string)' ,logo["initializationData"]),`
and then this fails with the error:

`InsufficientDataBytes: Tried to read 514314436127049056 bytes, only got 2297 bytes`

I tried the answer by Ake below which is to do some modifications:

```
for log in logs:
        if 'initializationData' in log[0]['args']:
            sanitized_log = dict(log[0])
            sanitized_log['args'] = dict(sanitized_log['args'])
            sanitized_log['args']['initializationData'] = w3.to_hex(sanitized_log['args']['initializationData'])
            sanitized_logs.append((sanitized_log,))
        else:
            sanitized_logs.append((log,))
```

However, if I do that, web3.eth_abi then complains

`TypeError: The` data`value must be of bytes type. Got <class 'str'>`

If I do `bytes.fromhex()` then I run into the old problem again of it being decoded. Could it be that SVG vectors (or maybe XML tags?) get decoded automatically by Python? Is there a workaround?

Here's an example of an event that I'm able to decode correctly because of how it turns up after `process_receipt`:

```
AttributeDict({'args': AttributeDict({'accountLogic': '0x915Af6753f03D2687Fa923b2987625e21e2991aE', 'account': '0xf147B323B00bE213FBB4F5cC148FD611a02D8845', 'initializationData': b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0eLlama Treasury\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'}), 'event': 'AccountCreated', 'logIndex': 38, 'transactionIndex': 2, 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0xacff465726f30a96f007287ceebe5d4eb7c170dc8c24579aa685ec4161cbedac'), 'address': '0x688576dC6b1AbaEe1d7Ee2B7c41Ee5D81BFD293c', 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x8a2a6f5248aa047d7e9fd20061fe3ff6c247555bde04916692bfbc063636d77d'), 'blockNumber': 4121274})
```

I also tried `(decode(...., strict=False)` but that didn't seem to be picked up.

EDIT 2:

After working on this for a while, I'm convinced, `decode()` with strict=False should be what does the trick but doesn't seem to be working for some reason. The code is still going to check and I get `InsufficientDataBytes` error when it should be skipped:

https://github.com/ethereum/eth-abi/blob/master/eth_abi/decoding.py#L517

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it a bug in web3.py, this is more of the default Python behavior to output bytes.

[Checking your code](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x6f5dfB0eaF832fF0D4204EC85184b634C7946457#code#F1#L93), `initializationData` is `bytes`, so that's how Python prints it using the `\x` notation.

One way to fix this would be to use the [Web3.to_hex](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.main.html#web3.Web3.to_hex) helper and just loop through the log.

Example:

```
from web3 import Web3
import json

node_endpoint = "NODE_ENDPOINT"
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(node_endpoint))

txhash = "0x25a57f565a2a8bb999d3344d9dc5ad305cc38263d253ae2a530d49542f5edb0b"

tx_receipt = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(txhash)

with open('CONTRACT_ABI.json', 'r') as abi_file:
    contract_abi = json.load(abi_file)

contract_address = "0x6f5dfB0eaF832fF0D4204EC85184b634C7946457"
event_name = "PolicyMetadataSet"

contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)
processed_logs = contract.events[event_name]().process_receipt(tx_receipt)

# convert initializationData to hex
modified_logs = []
for log in processed_logs:
    if 'initializationData' in log['args']:
        modified_log = dict(log)
        modified_log['args'] = dict(modified_log['args'])
        modified_log['args']['initializationData'] = w3.to_hex(modified_log['args']['initializationData'])
        modified_logs.append(modified_log)
    else:
        modified_logs.append(log)

print(modified_logs)
```

Comment: hey @Ake thank you for the prompt response. I've edited my question to add more context. I tried this but I run into other problems when I convert it to a hex string before I send to web3.eth_abi.decode() as it expects bytes rather than a string.